# Не запускается утилита из директории: /usr/bin/ на Alpine Linux

Tags: linux, alpine-linux

При попытке запустить утилиту: `./checkmk` в директории `/usr/bin`, я получаю следующее сообщение: `-ash: ./checkmk: not found.`

При использовании: `ls | grep checkmk`, утилита отображается в выводе команды.

При использовании: `ls -l checkmk` : `-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         15200 Oct 24  2022 checkmk`

Я пробовал запускать данную утилиту таким же способом на **Debian**,и это работает.
На **Debian**  и **Alpine** устанавливался тот же пакет: **check**, включающий в себя **checkmk**.

Данный пакет для Alpine: https://alpine.pkgs.org/3.14/alpine-main-aarch64/check-0.15.2-r0.apk.html

- Alpine: 3.17
- Debian: 11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/usr/bin/checkmk` - это скрипт, в первой строке которого написана магическая формула для запуска

```
#! /usr/bin/gawk -f
```

По-умолчанию в контейнере alpine нет `gawk`, поэтому вы видите ошибку `not found.`

добавить `gawk`:

```
apk add gawk
```

После этого заработает:

```
checkmk /usr/bin/checkmk
```

```
... длинный вывод
checkmk: Expected at least one #test line.
```

Работает, если одним словом.

PS

Интересно, почему у вас `checkmk` от 24 октября 2022 года? У меня в `alpine:latest` от 1 октября 2020:

```
$ docker run --rm alpine:latest sh -c 'apk add check && ls -l /usr/bin/checkmk'
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/1) Installing check (0.15.2-r0)
Executing busybox-1.35.0-r17.trigger
OK: 6 MiB in 15 packages
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         15200 Oct  1  2020 /usr/bin/checkmk
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, он действительно верный. Я решил проблему использованием ```awk```.

Comment: Хммм, у меня возникала ошибка при использовании ```awk```, но ради интереса я решил попробовать ```gawk``` и проблема решилась. Работа ```awk``` и ```gawk``` отличается на Alpine?

Comment: @Flex1sh `awk` в `alpine` из `busybox` - это минимальная реализация, соответствующая спецификации `awk` из стандарта Unix. В настоящих линуксах под именем `awk` скрывается `gawk`, поэтому там разница незаметна.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо!